How to USB KVM switch 3 monitors across 2 laptops?
I have 2 laptops that I need to be able to switch between frequently throughout the day.  I can't RDP from one to the other.  I have a 3 monitor setup (aside from the laptop screens) that I want to connect to both laptops so that whichever one is active has 3 monitors for the display.

1 Monitor is an LG 27BN85UN-B (https://www.amazon.com/LG-27BN85UN-B-DisplayHDR-FreeSyncTM-Stabilizer/dp/B09Z6F7TG8)
2 old Hanns-g 21" 1080s with HDMI/DVI ports
Laptops: Both laptops have 2 USB-C ports, and using this Anker
USB-C_to_dual-HDMI adapter
(https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0894B525X), I can set both of
them up to display on all 3 monitors.  1 USB-C to the USB-C input for
the LG monitor, and 1 USB-C to this dual HDMI adapter
(https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0894B525X) for the other 2
monitors.
I want to keep the 4k resolution for the LG monitor

I'm guessing that I need a USB keyboard/mouse and some sort of "USB-C KVM switch", but I'm not sure exactly what to look for.  Maybe something like this - https://www.amazon.com/KVM-Switch-Monitors-Computers-Displayport/dp/B0CRVMPJRH?
